# Where to store a Rails app's version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version

I would like to maintain a version of my Rails app, so that I can easily bump it on releases. I've stumbled upon different places of where to store this version inside a project, but I'm not sure where is the recommended way to store it:

- in `app/version.rb`, in a `MyRailsAppModule::VERSION`;
- in `app/version.rb`, in a `VERSION`;
- in `app/VERSION`, as plain text;
- in `VERSION`, as plain text.

I would especially appreciate some pro's for the chosen solution, as to why it is recommended to store it there.

Comment: If it is just about bumping on releases. How about Tagging Releases in Git - http://githowto.com/tagging_versions ?

Answer (score 1):

I worked in teams which deployed new versions more than 10 times a day. I think it it error prone to expect the developers to increased versions numbers on each deploy in a meaningful way.

I would suggest to configure your deploy script to tag the release in git with tags like `production/2015-01-13_13-18-42`.

That allows to see which tag was deployed in a given timeframe. Since git allows to checkout or revert to a tag, it is easy to rollback, test or just compare different versions.

Comment: I appreciate describing your past experience. Using only git tags sounds indeed alright, but we're having custom endpoints that print the app version, and those are taken from somewhere inside the app. Else, maybe the CI tool can bump this automatically, right? But I'm looking on where exactly to store this version.

Answer (score 1):

Working on a project which deploys versions every 2-4 weeks, I've traditionally stored versions in a module of application information constants, rather similar to your first example. Generally we've used a constant MAJOR_VERSION, MINOR_VERSION, PATCH_VERSION, and a method to display in the form of `"#{major}.#{minor}.#{patch}"`.

This is obviously more than necessary if you have no intention to display the version to users of your application, but we find it's effective, and an important part of our updating process is to update this file.

Comment: Yes. The first step in our development of a new iteration is to determine its scope, which in turn determines if we're updating to a new major, minor, or patch number. For us it's an important step either way because we have named version branches in our VCS (a corporate requirement), so someone was going to have to key in the numbers anyway. That said, it has proven useful to have these values in the code, as they are also leveraged in custom generators (for instance, we use a custom structure of seed files, with a new being generated every release and named according to the current version).

Comment: This was really helpful. But this means that if you fix the scope to, say, `2.0.0`, then this version will stick there for all environments prior to deploying to production, right? I would rather have more specific versions, say `2.0.0.pre.1` for a test/qa environment, `2.0.0.rc.1` for a staging/uat environment and only have `2.0.0` for a final/production state of the project.

Comment: That's entirely valid. There's certainly room for expansion of the versioning following this method. We operate via a fairly small development team, and find it beneficial to display the version to which we are developing, but we tend to flag at least the rails environment type with the version information through development (via a derivation of `Rails.env`). In our case it wouldn't make sense to have a change in the files for UAT or the like, as once it passes UAT it's entirely hands off for our developers.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for sharing!